# How do I get json body when I catch an error in httpClient

Tags: angular

I am using Angular with httpClient. The REST API returns a 422 Unprocessable Entity status in one case, which is received as an error. But the API also includes some JSON data that contains information about the error. How could I access this data?

Service

```js
createAnalyzer(body: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this._endpoint + '/api/analyzers', body)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(error) {
  let errorMessage = ''
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
  } else {
      // server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
  }
  return throwError(errorMessage)
}
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to do a `console.log(error)` in the error handler. It will provide a clear picture of the structure of the error and where your object is.

Comment: You can access status code in catchError, error.error.status is likely, and branch based on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of error responses can be found in the `error` property of the `catchError` callback arg.

So if you have the following response:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid credentials"
}
```

You could catch it using `catchError` like this:

```js
login(): Observable<any> {
  const url = ''; // TODO
  const body = {}; // TODO

  return this.http.post(url, body).pipe(
    tap(response => console.log('Success!')),
    catchError((err: any) => {
      const response = err.error;
      const message = response.message;
      console.log(`Error: ${message}`);
      return of(null);
    })
  );
}
```